# Masstransit limit threads

Tags: masstransit

We use masstransit 2.9.9 and have more than 100 servicebus instances in a single process. The problem is that masstransit consumes more than 600 threads, is it possible to limit thread count that masstransit uses?

Comment: why would you have 100 service bus? in a single service??

Comment: Process is host for 100 different services that consumes messages from different queues. So in masstransit 2.9.9 is the only way to use different queues is to create new Service Bus instances.

Comment: Any chance you can upgrade to 3.x, it scales much better in that respect, with significantly fewer connections to RMQ.